# We know if current is passed through spring it compress. I want to know how much is the attractive force that compresses it?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electricity

The formula I was trying to use to find the answer is:- check the image[image: formula I was trying to use]

Comment: Hello! It is [preferable](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10563/) to type out images of text; for formulae, one can use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/). Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The formula you have is for a segment in the field of a long straight wire (not the situation in a spring).  You will need the Biot-Savart formula adding contributions from each segment of each loop of the spring.  The result at each point will depend on the distance from each end of the spring.  A loop in the middle will be pulled equally in both directions. A loop near one end will be pulled toward the center. You might get a reasonable approximation by starring with the force between two circular loops separated by a known distance.